# Issue with SSH Aliases and Tunneling

Tags: ssh, alias

I want to connect to server B which is behind a firewall, using AliasForB. I SSH to server A first, and then from there I can SSH to server B. I am attempting to connect directly to server B by typing shorthand "ssh AliasForB". Both A and B require different usernames.

Based on a previous response, I used the following configuration, however, there is a small problem. When I close the connection, it appears that the connection on A is "killed" rather than closed gracefully. How can I fix this?

```
$> logout
Connection to B closed.
Killed by signal 1.
```

My configuration:

```
Host AliasForA
     Hostname FQDN.for.A.com
     User MyUsernameForA


Host AliasForB
     Hostname FQDN.for.B.com
     User MyUserNameForB
     ProxyCommand ssh AliasForA nc -w 3 %h %p
```

Comment: Why are you even worrying about this?  In the great grand scheme of things, having nc get a HUP barely even rates a mention in the badness stakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signal 1 is SIGHUP-- i.e. "hang up". It isn't "not graceful"-- netcat is just stopping because sshd sends it a SIGHUP. Yeah, yeah-- [other people are annoyed by it, too](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1118), but it's really no big deal. [Here's the backstory](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=223) about it, BTW.

Comment: I'd just add that SSH is behaving properly. If you have an application that you want to persist in the event of a SIGHUP, you can use nohup or launch it with a wrapper that intercepts the signal and does whatever you define as "graceful".